# Update a column with new information in a row that already exists using Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, csv

The ultimate goal is to learn how to update an existing rows data if an item in any of the columns change. For this, its important to update a row rather than remove/delete a row, because after automating the information being pulled from excel, there is manual data I have to enter to each CSV row.

An example would be, idKey's summary changes so the summary for existing idKey must be updated with the new summary without removing the occurrences I've manually entered for that idKey. Another example would be, idKey's status was under analysis two days ago while the defect was being looked at. This jira is now closed as a duplicate, idKey's status now needs to be changed from analysis to duplicate without ECG build that I've manually entered being removed.

I am using Pandas as my main library to establish my data frames for the incoming rows and to manipulate the CSV file. I have tried a few things that I've seen, however the most promising one I have found is possible the .drop() method for Pandas data frames, but I can't see past removing that row entirely without moving the manual data over to the new row.

This is how I've established my headers for my Pandas data frame:

```
xlsxHeaders=['Issue Key','Reporter','Created','Issue Type','Status','Vehicle','Components','Summary','Occurrence','Group Type','ECG Build','RC']

df = pd.DataFrame(xlsxHeaders) #this create the empty data frame
df = df.transpose()
if not os.path.isfile('JiraItems.csv'):
    df.to_csv('JiraItems.csv',mode='a', index=False,header=False)
else:
    skip
```

My jira query is called 'issues':

```
issues = jira.search_issues("**gotta remove this info for privacy**")
```

I've established the adding of jira items to the excel sheet without overriding existing items:

```
for issue in issues.values():
    newDate = issue.created
    idKey = issue.id
    reporter = issue.reporter
    issueType = issue.issue_type
    issueStatus = issue.status
    vehicleProgram  = issue.fields["vehicle_program"]
    issueComponents = issue.components
    issueSummary = issue.summary
    
    
    df2 = pd.DataFrame([str(idKey),str(reporter),str(newDate),str(issueType),str(issueStatus),str(vehicleProgram),str(issueComponents),str(issueSummary)])
    df2 = df2.transpose()
    df2.to_csv('JiraItems.csv',mode='a',index=False,header=False)
```

And lastly to drop an item from the CSV if it already exists I've tried this:

```
jiraItemsDF = pd.read_csv('JiraItems.csv')
jiraItemsDF = pd.DataFrame(jiraItemsDF)

jiraItemsDF.drop(jiraItemsDF.loc[jiraItemsDF['Issue Key'] == 'FNV-33314'], inplace=True, axis=1)
```

I must be doing something completely wrong here because when I print JiraItemsDF, the output is:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```

I've already considered the idea of skipping the entry of a row if the idKey comming in matches an idKey already existing, but again the ultimate goal is to learn how to update an existing row if any one of the columns change in status for an idKey or a issueSummary.

Any ideas or thoughts would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is in the drop. It is waiting for rows index to drop and you are sending a dataframe.

The result of `jiraItemsDF.loc[jiraItemsDF['Issue Key'] == 'FNV-33314']` is a DataFrame with all the rows that match this issue key.

This should work for you (take the indexes of the DataFrame and drop on `axis=0`)

```py
jiraItemsDF.drop(jiraItemsDF.loc[jiraItemsDF['Issue Key'] == 'FNV-33314'].index, inplace=True, axis=0)
```

By the way, if the ultimate goal is to learn how to update the DataFrame, you don't really have to drop the row.
You could do something like: `jiraItemsDF.loc[jiraItemsDF['Issue Key'] == 'FNV-33314'].index] = new_raw_values`

***Side note***:
`read_csv()` returns a DataFrame so you don't need this after `jiraItemsDF = pd.DataFrame(jiraItemsDF)`